# How does the wavelength of incident light and de-Broglie wavelength of molecules in a medium affect macroscopic properties of the medium?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, electromagnetic-radiation, material-science

Say I have a mixture of gases, or a liquid mixture. Now I am supposed to send photons through the mixture to study some macroscopic property of the mixture, e.g. refractive index, bulk modulus, density etc. by some procedure.

> *The question is:*
>
> How do the macroscopic properties of the mixture change or get
>   affected if:
>
> 1. the wavelength ($\lambda_i$) of incident light is **strictly greater than** the de-Broglie wavelength ($\lambda_d$) of the
>      particles/molecules present in the mixture, i.e. $\lambda_i >> \lambda_d$
> 2. the wavelength ($\lambda_i$) of incident light is **more or less comparable to** the de-Broglie wavelength ($\lambda_d$) of the
>      particles/molecules present in the mixture, i.e. $\lambda_i \approx \lambda_d$
> 3. the wavelength ($\lambda_i$) of incident light is **strictly lesser than** the de-Broglie wavelength ($\lambda_d$) of the
>      particles/molecules present in the mixture, i.e. $\lambda_i << \lambda_d$

Comment: This question is both unclear and too broad to me. 'Say I have a mixture of gases, or a liquid mixture. Now I am supposed to send photons through the mixture to study some macroscopic property of the mixture, e.g. refractive index, bulk modulus, density etc. by some procedure' is literally the most generally scattering/spectroscopy problem you could possibly pose. And what does it have to do with the de-Broglie length? You don't even say what interactions you have in this 'medium'.

Comment: @Wolpertinger "what does it have to do with the de-Broglie length?"...Exactly that's what I want to know ... Well, speaking of interactions, there may be scattering of photons, absorption of photons (and any other significant interaction that, you think, might be possible but I don't know of). It may be so that there is no relation between the properties and wavelengths in the question. But then please explain why there is no relation..

Answer (score 1):

First I don't understand why it matters it is a mixture really.

Then, in term of the momenta of particles, $p = h/\lambda$, your three cases are:

1. $p_i \ll p_d$
2. $p_i \approx p_d$
3. $p_i \gg p_d$

So I would say that in the first case, the incident light will have next to no effect on the medium. In the third case, the collision of the incident photons onto the medium atoms will impart enormous momentum onto them: the medium will be ripped apart (vaporising, etc). In the second, intermediate, case, it is impossible to be specific: one would need to know the details of the interactions between photons and medium particles.